# ASP.NET MVC 5 HttpPostedFileBase always null in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to send several files attended with some extra fields to server.

This is my model

```
// PreOrderInput contains some fields that getting populated correctly
public class PreOrderInputModel : PreOrderInput
{
    public new List<FileInputModel> Files { get; set; }
}

public class FileInputModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileContent { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DocumentTypeCodes DocumentTypeCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is the part of vue.js app that prepares form data

```
getFormData()
{
    var data = new FormData()

    data.append("LegalData[ProfileTypeCode]", this.model.type)
    data.append("LegalData[Inn]", this.model.inn)
    data.append("LegalData[OrganisationName]", this.model.organization)
    data.append("LegalData[Email]", this.model.email)
    data.append("Files[0][FileName]", this.model.files.passport.name)
    data.append("Files[0][FileContent]", this.model.files.passport.file)
    data.append("Files[0][DocumentTypeCode]", this.documentTypeCode.SNILS)

    return data
},
```

The app posts following data (example)

```
mimeType: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm

------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LegalData[ProfileTypeCode]"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LegalData[Inn]"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LegalData[OrganisationName]"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LegalData[Email]"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Files[0][FileName]"

AdmittedSkzi.xlsx
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Files[0][FileContent]"; filename="AdmittedSkzi.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Files[0][DocumentTypeCode]"

11
------WebKitFormBoundaryUTk0Jj2CJJCLZOYm--
```

This is controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePreOrder(PreOrderInputModel preOrderInput)
{
    preOrderInput.CreatorLogin = UserLogin;
    return Json(_customerPreOrderService.CreatePreOrder(UserLogin, preOrderInput));
}
```

Although Request.Files contains posted file data, preOrderInput.Files[0].FileContent is null.

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending property names to `FormData` that do not relate to your model.

As you have noted yourself, you use `preOrderInput.Files[0].FileContent` to access the value in the controller method - i.e. dot notation to access a property of a complex object, therefore the property names in `FormData` must match that notation.

Since `preOrderInput` is the name of the parameter in the method, you just drop that from the property name, so it should be

```
var data = new FormData()
....
data.append("Files[0].FileContent", this.model.files.passport.file); // not "Files[0][FileContent]"
```

and ditto for you other property names you are adding to `FormData`